# sql syntax error while symfony doctrine:generate-module command

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

So, my problem is..

i`m trying to execute this command:

> php symfony **doctrine:generate-module** --env="my_env" --non-verbose-templates backend city_theme CityTheme

After a pause, i get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?) LIMIT 1' at line 1. Failing Query: "**SELECT c.id AS c__id, c.city_theme_id AS c__city_theme_id, c.description AS c_*description, c.excursions AS c*_excursions, c.image AS c_*image, c.keywords AS c*_keywords, c.name AS c_*name, c.slug AS c*_slug, c.title AS c__title FROM city_theme_data c WHERE (c.city_theme_id = ?) LIMIT 1**"

My schema.yml for this model is:

```
CityTheme: 
  columns: 
    city_id: integer 
    lang: string(2) 
    guides: string 
  relations: 
    City: 
      class: City 
      local: city_id 
      foreign: id 
      foreignAlias: CityThemes 
      onDelete: CASCADE 

CityThemeData: 
  columns: 
    city_theme_id: integer 
    description: {type: string(255)} 
    excursions: string 
    image: {type: string(255)} 
    keywords: {type: string(255)} 
    name: {type: string(255)} 
    slug: {type: string(255)} 
    title: {type: string(255)} 
  relations: 
    CityTheme: 
      class: CityTheme 
      local: city_theme_id 
      foreign: id 
      foreignAlias: CityThemesData 
      onDelete: CASCADE
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that doctrine is trying to execute a prepared statement instead of preparing it... strange.

Comment: On a side note, this is wrong:     excursions: string

Comment: Oh, as i thought, string type is alias of MySQL TEXT type, and i need exactly TEXT field, because it will contain comma-sepereted values with unexpectable length.. (like 123,534,6654,4353,...)

Comment: then the type you really need is probably `array` rather than string. Apart from this error, do you have a stack trace. Are you using the latest version of symfony 1.4 ?

Comment: sure, i have the latest version of symfony 1.4, downloaded from home-site.

Comment: This is super-weird. Are you using a custom environment (i.e. is there a particular reason you used the `--env="my_env"` option? Have you tried without it, using the default dev environment?)